# What were English 'rules restricting marriage'?

Tags: england, marriage

I am reading the book by Steven LeBlanc and Katherine Register, Constant battles, (2003).
It is about history of warfare, but on p. 165 I found the mysterious sentence:

> For example, rules can be passed and enforced restricting marriage to people with enough wealth to set up a
>   household, as was the case in England,

Can anyone explain what they mean? I've never heard about "rules restricting marriage" on the basis of wealth, in England, or any other Christian country. Unfortunately they do not specify the time period. They mention existence of such rules at least twice in the book, as something known, without giving any further detail.

Edit. I summarize the prevailing opinion in this long discussion: the authors made this up. No such rules were ever "passed and enforced".

Comment: Might be useful to start by looking at [Gretna Greene](https://www.gretnagreen.com/an-introduction-to-gretna-green-a984). I don't know, but I suspect that is the beginning of the answer.

Comment: @m: [Marriage Act 1753](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriage_Act_1753) answers most issues I believe. The UK Parliament site also [sheds insight](https://www.parliament.uk/about/living-heritage/transformingsociety/private-lives/relationships/overview/lawofmarriage-/)

Comment: @Pieter Gerkins: I did not find any mentioning of "wealth sufficient to set up a household" in these documents.

Comment: @Alex: Precisely. Your author has been reading too much Jane Austen, and believing everything read.

Comment: @Pieter Gerkins: so you seem to say that there were some social rules (which applied only to certain classes of society) but no formal laws. This is what I suspected.

Comment: The text of the *Marriages Act 1753* (i.e. "*said Act of the Twenty-sixth Year of the Reign of His said late Majesty King George the Second*") is not online but the [Marriages Confirmation Act 1825 is](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Geo4/6/92/enacted)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens "1753: An Act for the Better Preventing of Clandestine Marriage. 26 Geo. II. c. 33" is online at http://statutes.org.uk/site/the-statutes/eighteenth-century/1753-26-geo-2-c-33-prevention-of-clandestine-marriages/

Comment: @Henry: Great! I didn't know about that alternate (unofficial) site.

Comment: Not in England but in the US, the author Nathaniel Hawthorne was engaged but wasn't "in a position to marry" because he was not financially secure (1835). He didn't feel able to marry for seven more years. This same theme is echoed in Trollope's "Framley Parsonage". This concept of being able to support a wife is a social more, not a law, and was most probably the basis behind getting the father's consent at engagement - a good father is unlikely to consent to his daughter living in poverty because of an impecunious suitor.

Comment: The catholic church in Trent (2 centuries before) started requiring 'form' (i.e., the publication procedures and the formal ceremony) exactly to avoid clandestine marriages. But I also guess that your financial requirement should be informal custom, not a law. Otherwise, how would the precise limit be defined?

Comment: @Jurp: That has nothing to do with laws, though, but with one's personal opinions.  (And of course customs, to some extent.)  It's even the case with some people (but unfortunately not everyone) in modern times, especially if they expect the marriage to result in children.

Comment: @jamesqf - As I noted in my comment, these were examples of social MORES and not laws. I have done some research on this question and like others, could find no laws stating that people had to have property to marry.

Answer (score 2):

England notably had a late age of first marriage due to socially enforced cultural rules around appropriate economic capacity to maintain a household. This “late age of first marriage” household reproduction strategy was common to north Europe and the petits bourgeois. England was in north Europe. England had a wealthier peasantry prior to 1750 than many other locations and additionally had a large petits bourgeois.

While not unlawful, early marriage was economically costly, invited social censure, and could result in lack of access to productive property or disinheriting.

The core “rule” was that men needed to restrict marriage until capable of independently maintaining a household of their class at the social standard expected by their class. Women’s first marriage was much less restricted as women did not generally control social property at time of first marriage.